# How to generate a strict json schema with pydantic?

Tags: python, jsonschema, pydantic

I recently started to use pydandic to generate JSON schemas for validating data but I found the by default the generated schema does not complain about unknown keys inside my BaseModel.

Example:

```
class Query(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: Optional[str]
```

The generated schema would pass validation even if the object has other attributes than the two one mentioned here.

How can I assure validation will fail if someone adds a "foo: bar" property?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a configuration on your model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra
class Query(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: Optional[str]
    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid
```

It defaults to `Extra.ignore`, the other option is `Extra.allow` which adds any extra fields to the resulting object.

You can also just use the strings `"ignore"`, `"allow"`, or `"forbid"`

Here are all the model config options you can use:

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/

Comment: That was quick and awesome! Thanks. I tried searching for strict in docs before posting it, but no luck.

Comment: Maybe we also know how to deal with https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/2266 ?

Comment: @sorin you can use `a_valid_identifier: Annotation = Field(alias="not a valid-identifier")`.